# IIS 7 and PHP response timeout for large object

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, fastcgi

my coworkers and I have been stumped on this issue for several weeks.  We have a PHP 5.3 web application hosted in an IIS 7 environment.  The application fetches result sets from a SQL Server 2012 database backend and sends it as a JSON object back to the client.

The problem comes when a request is made that results in an object size that exceeds about 4MB.  So each time a response exceeds this size, the connection gets reset and results in error.  I've confirmed this on the local server by using Curl and this very useful [.JQ JSON command-line parser](http://stedolan.github.com/jq/).  Using these tools, when I run a request on the IIS web server hosting the application it completes responses < 4MB successfully, but fails to complete responses > 4MB with the Curl(56) error *"Connection was reset"*.

Some additional notes:

- the query running directly against the database only takes about 20 seconds to complete, so DB performance is not the issue.
- We run the Zend Framework on top of Apache in our local desktop dev environments; but this issue is not reproducible in any of them.  The same > 4MB response object that fails on the web server, completes successfully when making the same request to our local Apache hosted environment.

I combed the web server's IIS 7 config settings and made the following changes

- I've increased max allowed content length and URL length to 30MB from their defaults.
- PHP, FastCGI and IIS connection timeout settings are set at 5-minutes each.  I've run smaller queries that take up to a minute to complete, but a valid response always comes back as long as it's less than 4MB.

I started reading that IIS 7's response buffer cache mechanism may also affect PHP application performance, but I'm still getting familiar with this feature.  If there's anyone who's had a similar issue in the past or could provide some insight into what the problem might be, I am open.  At this point I'm not sure what else could be causing this issue on the IIS 7 web server.

Comment: Please *please **please*** do  not put the answer to your question in the OP. Post the answer as an answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [Zend_Json](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.html) or PHP built-in [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function for encoding? Check PHP memory_limit setting in php.ini.

Also check PHP error reporting and error logging settings (error_reporting and error_log directives in php.ini).

I guess PHP would output something or quietly terminate the script execution instead of resetting the HTTP connection.

Take a look at the logs on the web server to find out more details:

- Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application / System > see if PHP FastCGI worker processes are crashing
- IIS log files > pin down the response codes and statuses for the failed HTTP requests
- Use the "Failed Request Tracing Rules" in IIS to get more details for the failed requests
- Eventually, use Process Monitor (ProcMon), filter it to show only application pool(s) (w3wp.exe) and PHP/FastCGI processes to examine PHP and IIS activity at the given moment

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with curl request taking more than 10 mins with following error

**Curl error: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054**

Root cause was by default curl terminates the request after 5 mins if requested server didn't respond. I tried increasing execution time with the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3600, but for some reason curl ignored this setting.

Solution:
What worked for me is setting keep alive flag in curl options along with timeout flag **CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE => 1**.